# Speedfan not showing all harddrives' smart data

Tags: hard-drive, smart, speedfan

I installed speedfan and used it to look at my HDDs' smart data. All 5 of my drives appeared without issue. However, I have now added an additional 2 SATA HDDs to my existing (already in use) SATA controller and added them in Window 7's software mirror raid.

My new drives do not appear in speed fan, what can I do to view their SMART data?

Comment: Not all hard drives provide the same information.

Comment: Discovered the data in another program. Strange it never shown up in speedfan